# Customize error messages on django-registration

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I have a question about django-registration (https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration), but I can't find their issue tracker or a mailing list for it, so I'll try my luck here.

My application enables login via OpenID and login/password.

Some users "forget their password" on FS on try to reset it ([here](http://freedomsponsors.org/accounts/password/reset/)), but then they get the message:

> The user account associated with this e-mail address cannot reset the password.

With no further explanations.
(You can try and reset *my* password - just type my email (tonylampada at gmail dot com) there to see the error message.

I want to customize that message. A better message would be:

> The user account associated with this e-mail address cannot reset the password.
>   This happens because the user account was created with an OpenID or OAuth provider (tipically Google, Facebook, MyOpenID, etc). 
>   To see the login provider(s) associated with this account, take a look at the [user profile](http://freedomsponsors.org/core/user/2/tonylampada).

What is the easiest way to tell django-registration that?

Thanks!

PS: This issue on Github: https://github.com/freedomsponsors/www.freedomsponsors.org/issues/191 (just in case you're feeling like making a pull request today :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-registration uses views from `django.contrib.auth`.

In this case: `reset_password()` [github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L130)

Since this is no class based view, you can't override/inherit from it, but you can pass in a PasswordResetForm from django.contrib.auth.forms

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class CustomResetForm(PasswordResetForm):

       def validate(self, value):
            #pseudocode
            if user.cant_reset_pw:
               raise ValidationError("The user account associated with this e-mail address cannot reset the password. and so forth..")

            super(CustomResetForm, self).validate(value)
```

You'll have to wire things together by overriding the url `r'^password/change/$'` to point to a custom function that calls `django.contrib.auth.passwort_reset()` with your `CustomResetForm`.